# ENDORSEMENT_FAILURE while creating key value via putState for 3 Orgs network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have set up a fabric network of three organizations. 1 endorser peer each. 1 orderer across all three. I packaged the contract code(node) and installed on all three. Instantiated it via CLI of one of the peer.

Points to consider:

1. My chaincode tries to create a key value or I should say update the 
   World State.On invoking the function that does so, I always end up 
   getting [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE].
2. I have specified AND policy. OR policy seems to work fine. But I 
   have a scenario where AND is the necessity.
3. I invoke the chaincode via CLI of one peer. All other peers start 
   showing activity but ends up saying [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE].
   Exact Error : "VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 
   3c0f7b5c5f81b5c261d1a981720273cdc617424ea264b157898dd17ad2de07ce 
   returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: 
   signature set did not satisfy policy".
4. I have monitored the chaincode containers of all three orgs. Only 
   the the container of the chaincode corresponding to the calling peer 
   shows activity.
5. As I perceive from my reading of the book Hands-On Blockchain with 
   Hyperledger, all the peers execute the chaincode. But in my case, 
   nothing is happening on other two peers' chaincode container.

I would be grateful to obtain help on this issue.